# Eclipse tab titles not displayed correctly

Tags: java, eclipse

**I tried vainly to reinstall my IDE but still the same problem.**

[image: project tabs titles are[enter image description here][1] not displayed correclty]

Comment: I think we need a larger picture to understand. Maybe zoom the view so we see how the full title looks?

Comment: Okey, I added a larger screenshot :)

Comment: Possibly this [problem report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=551965) caused by fonts on your system. See the problem report for solutions.

Comment: greg-449 it worked thank you so much, I needed to delete some fonts I installed on top of default ones of windows 10 :)

Answer (score 4):

I've the same problem.
In my case the issue was provocated by fonts. I've installed on windows "Segoe UI" (a google font). I don't konw why but this font was becomed the system default font.
To fix the issue:
In eclipse I've changed manually the font with old one "Segoe UI Symbol" (Windows > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Font > View and Editor Folders > Part title font) Edit... and change font.