# JAVA eclipse pane(window) language is crashing

Tags: java, eclipse

I have just installed Eclipse to a new environment, and all the languages in pane (window) are crashing.

[Image here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHkBI.png)

Is anyone experiencing the similar or does anyone know solution to this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61743437/eclipse-tab-titles-not-displayed-correctly ?

Comment: @dratenik  Thanks a million! I had a difficult time finding right word to search